# Display the underlying code in airflow when the python_callable is decorated

Tags: python, airflow, python-decorators

I'm using airflow for daily tasks. Most of my tasks take the current date as an argument.

To avoid having all my tasks extracting the date from context and parsing it (which is a lot of boiler plate), I've introduced a wrapper/decorator

```py
def task_abc(date: datetime.date):
    print(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    
def wrap_task(task):
    def wrapped_task(**context):
        task(datetime.date.fromisoformat(context['ds']))
    return wrapped_task
        
wrapped_abc = wrap_task(task_abc)

wrapped_abc(ds='2020-10-11')

with xxx as dag:
  my_dag_task = PythonOperator(task_id='task_abc', provide_context=True, python_callable=wrapped_abc)
```

It works like a charm, excepted in the web UI the `python_callable` shows the boiler plate (`wrapped_task`)  rather than the actual code that is being called.

Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointing the source of a decorated function to the original source is a common problem in Python which can be easily solved with `functools`

```
import datetime
import functools
import inspect


def task_abc(date: datetime.date):
    print(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))


def wrap_task(task):
    def wrapped_task(**context):
        task(datetime.date.fromisoformat(context['ds']))
    return wrapped_task


def wrap_task_with_source(task):
    def wrapped_task(**context):
        task(datetime.date.fromisoformat(context['ds']))
    return functools.update_wrapper(wrapped_task, task)


wrapped_abc = wrap_task(task_abc)
wrapped_abc_with_source = wrap_task_with_source(task_abc)

print('without source:')
print(inspect.getsource(wrapped_abc))
print('with source:')
print(inspect.getsource(wrapped_abc_with_source))

wrapped_abc(ds='2020-10-11')
wrapped_abc_with_source(ds='2020-10-11')
```

Will print:

```
without source:
    def wrapped_task(**context):
        task(datetime.date.fromisoformat(context['ds']))

with source:
def task_abc(date: datetime.date):
    print(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

2020-10-11
2020-10-11
```

One important caveat is when using partial, see [airflow source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/349b0811c3022605426ba57d30936240a7c2848a/airflow/utils/code_utils.py#L37)